# SetTimeout + fs.writeFile erases my object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an object "rooms" and I'am trying to print it's content into a file "logging.json" every 10 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  fs.writeFile('./logging.json',JSON.stringify(rooms,null,'\t'),function(err) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('done');
  });
}, 10000);
```

The first time (after 10 seconds) it works and I got my file logging.json completed. But the second time that the function is called, the content of my object "rooms" is erased and the logging.json file that I obtain is also empty.

Also, the rest of my program works correctly withaout this portion of code so I don't think it's coming from something else.

Could you tell please my why I'm getting this and how to fix it?

EDIT: This is what I get in the console when I try to print the my room object.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node serveur.js`
[ { username: 'Bob', message: 'Hello' },
done
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node serveur.js`
[]
done
```

Also, I don't get why the server restars every 10 seconds, it's not supposed to.

Comment: Try to use appendFile instead or add the 'a' flag like writeFile(file, data, {'flag':'a'}, function)

Comment: Same thing with appendFile, my object gets erased again.

Comment: I just run your code. it works ok for second time too. 
Is your program erasing rooms objsec ? 
could you add details ? or more code ?

Comment: ofc.... you need setInterval not setTimeout

Comment: Yes, I can see through the console that all the attributes of my object rooms are emptied everytime the function is launched. Also, I use nodemon and the server restarts everytime the function is launched.

Comment: @Mit try running you app with `nodemon --ignore logging.json`. Every time you write to that file your app is restarting because nodemon detects a change in your folder. Presumably that's not the behaviour you're after?

Comment: Thanks dan! It works now.

Comment: @Mit Great! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `nodemon`, you need to tell `nodemon` to ignore the file you're writing otherwise you entire app will restart every your update the file. This can be done via the command line like this:

```
nodemon --ignore logging.json app.js
```

Or by updating your `nodemon` config.

If you want to run the function every 10 seconds, you need to use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` will only run once, in 10 seconds.

To replace all content in the file every 10 seconds:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let count = 0

setInterval(function() {
    fs.writeFile('./test.txt', count, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}, 10000)
```

To append the file every 10 seconds:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let count = 0

setInterval(function() {
    const text = count++ + '\n'
    fs.appendFile('./test.txt', text, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}, 10000)
```

Comment: Yes I want to replace all the file. I've also tried with setInterval and I get the same result...

Comment: @Mit Ah ok. So every 10 seconds you want to replace the content of the file with the rooms object?

Comment: Yes, knowing that the object has probably been updated since.